# How to bind UIButton located in UITableViewCell with Data Model located in View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

community! 
I'm coding a game and facing difficulties connecting the UIButton to the exact CellData Model located in SectionModel.
Here is the thing.
I've got TableView that consists of Sections and Rows. Section are defined in SectionModel, Rows in DataModel:

```
lazy var sections: [SectionModel] = [
    SectionModel(
        name: "Basic",
        open: true,
        data: [
            CellData(locationName: K.hospital , isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.church, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.embassy, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.restaurant, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.house, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.cafe, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.factory, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.shop, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.flowersMarker, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.bikeFixer, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.gym, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.bar, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.park, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.garden, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.nightClub, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.castle, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.basement, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.bank, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.policeOffice, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.school, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.bakery, isChosen: true),
            CellData(locationName: K.market, isChosen: true)
    ])]
```

Buttons are defined if UITableView cell as a collection :

```
 @IBOutlet var locationsCollection: [UIButton]!
```

I set up Buttons Title via CelForRowAt indexPath method:

```
 for (i, location) in cell.locationsCollection.enumerated() {
        if i < section.data.count {
            location.setTitle(section.data[i].locationName, for: .normal)
            location.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            location.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .medium)
            location.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center

            location.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            location.backgroundColor = .white
            location.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            location.layer.borderWidth = 1 }}
```

IBAction is in the UITableViewCell and it passes the method via protocol to the ViewCOntrolles, so when I press on the button, the border width changes:

[image]

What I also desire to achieve - to change the value in the CellData Model, when I press the button it changes to false. Could you, guys, enlighten me, please?

Comment: Create UIButton Collection. Then assign tags to each button by looping over your Collection. At that point you can simply use an @IBAction and check the UIButton.Tag in a switch statement or conditional check of some sort.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea! It helped a lot! I also set the cell tag to keep track of what section am I currently at!